# MySQL Workbench - How to update 2 different schemas from one EER Diagram?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is it possible to use one EER Diagram currently associated with a schema called mydb with another schema mydb2?

Comment: You should reassign the solution to David I. or at least give him a vote since this is now fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not currently. You can only compare two databases if they have the same name. It's a known bug:

- [Workbench not able to synchronize schemas with different names](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45533)
- [Rename database schema makes synchronisation impossible](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61211)